# How to send message from one to other user with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want make custom message web app, which users can send messages each other(not chat, just sending message). I've message model and message form, but i don't know about views and templates looks like. I can't found any tutorial or something about this, most of i found just libraries or something packages. Then, how about this views and templates?

here my models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Message(models.Model):
     sender = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name="sender")
     receiver = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name="receiver")
     message_file = models.FileField(upload_to='mails/')
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     unread = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Message

class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Message
        fields  =[
            'sender',
            'receiver',
            'message_file',
        ]
```

Thanks in adnvance

Comment: you must do more research, create html pages with forms for users to interact with your site, and connect them to your views.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a form, I will give you a simple example using a more basic approach. What you will want is something along the lines of this:

**views.py**

```
class SendMessageView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        receiver_id = request.POST.get('receiver_id', '')
        file = request.FILES.get('file', '')
        Message.objects.create(sender=request.user, receiver__id=receiver_id, message_file=file)
        return render(request, 'success.html', {})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('message/send/', views.SendMessageView.as_view(), name="send_message")
```

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'send_message' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver_id" value="{{ receiver.id }}" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

Comment: how come the post method gives result using 'get' in view!!

Comment: `.get()` is just is just a method of `request.POST` and `request.GET` which allows to get the values, or return a value if there is nothing (in this case it will return a blank string if POST or GET are empty)